# use express-session secure in app deployed to google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express-session

I have a Next app that communicates with my node.js server.

In dev mode, everything works fine even when deployed to Google, but when I change the environment, this is where the problem begins.

Basically, I have this express-session setup:

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'){
    app.set('trust proxy', 1);
}

app.use(
    session(
        { 
            //store: redisStore,
            secret: process.env.SERVER_SESSION_SECRET,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
                httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : true, 
                sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? false : 'none', 
                domain: process.env.BASE_URL || 'localhost',
                proxy: true,
            }
        }
    )
);
```

When I fetch the API, this should set a cookie, but it's not doing that. I know the problem may be related to HTTP and HTTPS, but my URL is already HTTPS (I just added my custom domain). Do I need to configure something else in GAE?

Don't know if this is helpful but my `app.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
env: standard
runtime: nodejs18
service: stg
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

Comment: Have you added the `trust proxy` setting in your js file? It should be like this: `app.set('trust proxy', true);`. Reference: [HTTPS and forwarding proxies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies)

Comment: Thanks I have `app.set('trust proxy', true);` inside an `if`, that was actually the problem. I had my env variables wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my previous comment as an answer.

The issue was resolved by adding the following code inside the js file:

```
app.set('trust proxy', true);
```

Also, make sure that `env` variables are correct.

You can check this documentation on [HTTPS and forwarding proxies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies) which contains the `trust proxy` setting for Express.js.